# Error sorting listView items using Collection.sort

Tags: android, listview

Hi I want to sort my listView items alphabetically. I know there are other questions on SOF regarding this subject, but none of the answers worked for me.

```
public class myList extends Activity{

// Tab Host
TabHost th;
LinearLayout tab1, tab2;

//List
ListView myListView;
String string_list[] = { "String1", "String2", "String3", "String", "String5", "String6"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // XML File
    setContentView(R.layout.main_list);

    // TabHost
    initializeTab();

    // ListView
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,string_list);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter); 

            myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    Collections.sort(myListView, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
}
```

I get an error on my `Collections.sort` statement that says:

```
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ListView, Comparator<String>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Collections.sort(myListView, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

to

```
Arrays.sort(string_list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

and then

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,string_list);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct class is the following:

```
public class myList extends Activity {

    // Tab Host
    TabHost th;
    LinearLayout tab1, tab2;

    //List
    ListView myListView;
    String[] string_list = { "String1", "String2", "String3", "String", "String5", "String6"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // XML File
        setContentView(R.layout.main_list);

        // TabHost
        initializeTab();

        // ListView
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView1);
        Arrays.sort(string_list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,string_list);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }
}
```

Please note, that `Array` != `Collection`

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would be to use adapter's `sort` method:

```
adapter.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```